# Getting Error in VS : There is no editor available for Can't open .cs?

Tags: c#

My computer shut down while working on a project and when I opened C# again and recovered it, I got an error saying

```
There is no editor available 'for filename.cs'
Make sure the application for the file type (.cs) is installed
```

And now I can't access my code at all.

I'm using Visual C# 2013 express.

I tried opening it directly and it brings up C# but the .cs file opens up in notepad. The file size is 13kb so it didn't get deleted. And there is still a working .exe in the debug folder of the last run. Is there any way to recover the code?any one have the idea how can get the my file and code please help me.i am also go on this folder and check but here this file is not available."C:\Users\I BALL\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Backup Files"

Comment: " the .cs file opens up in notepad. [...] Is there any way to recover the code?" - I'm confused. Is the cs file present and works in notepad or is it lost and you are trying to recover it? It sounds like your visual studio has got screwed up somehow to which I'd suggest a reinstall but then you also talk about recovering code so I'm unclear on whether it has nuked your code as well...

Comment: When you right-click a cs file in your solution and choose "Open With…" from the menu, what is selected in the dialogue?

Comment: @stuartd which option select in the Open with menu ? can you please tell me

Comment: Install Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition, VS2013 is very ancient...

Comment: @coderwill - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rmhq6.png